# Mean (or any other statistic) calculated omitting zeroes

Tags: r

Imagine that I have a data frame and a column. How do I calculate the mean (or any other descriptive statistic) without zeroes? i.e. if in a column I have [32, 0, 0, 34, 2] I want to have mean of [32, 34, 2] only.

**edit**: any ideas how to approach it `data.table` library?

Comment: What about mode or median? 1st quartile ? 2nd quartile?

Comment: ````mean(x[x != 0])```` if you have negative values

Comment: @mkropkowski What is your question? How to exclude zeros from a vector or how to calculate summary statistics?

Comment: How to calculate different summary statistics excluding zeroes (but without changing vector/data frame column we use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `purrr` approach illustrating several techniques:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(
  A = sample(0:4, 10, replace = TRUE),
  B = sample(0:4, 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df
#>    A B
#> 1  2 3
#> 2  0 1
#> 3  1 0
#> 4  1 4
#> 5  4 2
#> 6  1 2
#> 7  3 4
#> 8  4 2
#> 9  4 4
#> 10 0 3
```

---

**Method 1:** Explicit argument to `discard()`

```
map_df(df, ~ tibble(
  sum = discard(., . == 0) %>% sum,
  median = discard(., . == 0) %>% median,
  percentile_25 = discard(., . == 0) %>% quantile(probs = 0.25)
), .id = "var")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   var     sum median percentile_25
#>   <chr> <int>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 A        20    2.5             1
#> 2 B        25    3               2
```

**Method 2:** Abstract the argument into an `as_mapper` to create a new function, `discard_at_zero`:

```
discard_at_zero <- as_mapper(~ discard(., . == 0))

map_df(df, ~ tibble(
  sum = discard_at_zero(.) %>% sum,
  median = discard_at_zero(.) %>% median,
  percentile_25 = discard_at_zero(.) %>% quantile(probs = 0.25)
), .id = "var")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   var     sum median percentile_25
#>   <chr> <int>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 A        20    2.5             1
#> 2 B        25    3               2
```

**Method 3:** Generalize that argument so you can pass it as the second value (.y); creating a `discard_at_value` (below we are discarding elements == 1).

```
discard_at_value <- as_mapper(~ discard(.x, .x == .y))

map_df(df, ~ tibble(
  sum = discard_at_value(., 1) %>% sum,
  median = discard_at_value(., 1) %>% median,
  percentile_25 = discard_at_value(., 1) %>% quantile(probs = 0.25)
), .id = "var")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   var     sum median percentile_25
#>   <chr> <int>  <int>         <dbl>
#> 1 A        17      3             1
#> 2 B        24      3             2
```

**Method 4:** Using `purrr::partial` to pre-fill our `discard_at_value` function and create `discard_at_zero2`:

```
discard_at_zero2 <- partial(discard_at_value, .y = 0)
map_df(df, ~ tibble(
  sum = discard_at_zero2(.) %>% sum,
  median = discard_at_zero2(.) %>% median,
  percentile_25 = discard_at_zero2(.) %>% quantile(probs = 0.25)
), .id = "var")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   var     sum median percentile_25
#>   <chr> <int>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 A        20    2.5             1
#> 2 B        25    3               2
```

Comment: How can I apply your approach to the entire data frame at once? How to get any of this statistics from the entire data frame? (not separated by columns)

Comment: @mkropkowski I am not sure what you are asking. The statistics are calculated for the entire (each column) data.frame in this example. The data.frame in this example is `df`. Perhaps ask a new questions and/or edit your question with a small example of your data.frame and the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more general solution. `nozero()` takes a function as an argument, and further arguments are passed to that function using `...`.

```
nozero <- function(x, FUN, ...) {
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    FUN(x[x != 0], ...)
}

z <- c(1, 9, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 6, 4, 1)

dtf <- data.frame(A=c(2, 5, 0, -2, 1),
                  B=c(-6, 0, 6, 4, 2))

nozero(z, mean)
nozero(z, median)
nozero(z, quantile, 0.25)
nozero(unlist(dtf), quantile, 0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for each column, you can just create a function that selects what you're interested in and then use apply to that function and for each list got do a lapply with the wanted statistic:

```
library(dplyr)
Data<- data.frame(col1= c(0,1,0,3,5),
                  col2 = c(2,4,5,6,0))
NoZero <- function(vec){
  vec <- vec[vec!=0]
  return(vec)
}
Data %>% apply(2, NoZero) %>%lapply(summary)
$`col1`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       2       3       3       4       5 

$col2
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00    3.50    4.50    4.25    5.25    6.00
```

Comment: What if I want for the entire data frame?

Comment: What if i want to have mode or median or 1 st quartile?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `weighted.mean` and set a weight of 1 for nonzero values and 0 otherwise:

```
x <- c(32,0,0,34,2)

weighted.mean(x, x != 0)
# [1] 22.66667
```